# Dill/Pickling Error: odd numbers of set items

Tags: pickle, dill

I have a very strange error that cannot be reproduced anywhere except my production environment. What does this error mean? I get it when I try run the following piece of code:

```
  serialized_object = dills.dumps(object)
  dill.loads(serialized_object)
```

pickle.UnpicklingError: odd number of items for SET ITEMS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd never seen this before, so I looked at the source code.  See here: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/f24143b25e4f83368ff6182bebe14f885073015c/Modules/_pickle.c#L5914  it seems that the implication is that you have a corrupted or hostile pickle.

Based on the OP's comments, I think I see the workaround. I'll have to determine the impact of the workaround, and it will have to be integrated into `dill`, but for now here it is:

```
>>> import StringIO as io
>>> f = io.StringIO()
>>> import dill
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.array([1])
>>> y = (x,)
>>> p = dill.Pickler(f)
>>> p.dump(x)
>>> f.getvalue()
"cnumpy.core.multiarray\n_reconstruct\np0\n(cnumpy\nndarray\np1\n(I0\ntp2\nS'b'\np3\ntp4\nRp5\n(I1\n(I1\ntp6\ncnumpy\ndtype\np7\n(S'i8'\np8\nI0\nI1\ntp9\nRp10\n(I3\nS'<'\np11\nNNNI-1\nI-1\nI0\ntp12\nbI00\nS'\\x01\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00'\np13\ntp14\nb."
>>> p.dump(y)
>>> f.getvalue()
"cnumpy.core.multiarray\n_reconstruct\np0\n(cnumpy\nndarray\np1\n(I0\ntp2\nS'b'\np3\ntp4\nRp5\n(I1\n(I1\ntp6\ncnumpy\ndtype\np7\n(S'i8'\np8\nI0\nI1\ntp9\nRp10\n(I3\nS'<'\np11\nNNNI-1\nI-1\nI0\ntp12\nbI00\nS'\\x01\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00'\np13\ntp14\nb.(g5\ntp15\n."
>>> dill.loads(_)
array([1])
>>>
```

Comment: It turned out that this was caused by a bug in dill. Look in reply below

Answer (score 0):

```
import dill
import numpy as np

x = np.array([1])

y = (x,)

dill.dumps(x)

dill.loads(dill.dumps(y))
```

This will throw an out of index exception. The reason is because there is a special function that is registered to serialize numpy array objects. That special function uses the global Pickler to store the serialized data instead of the Pickler that is passed as an argument. To fix it, I used the Pickler that is passed to the argument instead. I'm not sure if it breaks anything else in the dill though.

Comment: can you gist what you did, or otherwise post to an issue on github?  If it's due to a bug in `dill` and you have a workaround then I can test the impact of your patch.

Comment: I think I see what you are saying you did… you just used `dill.Pickler.dumps` instead of `dill.dumps`.  Is that correct?  That's a perfectly fine approach, and good to know.  I'd like to add a patch in `Pickler` method that handles `numpy` arrays, so can you confirm the above?

Comment: https://github.com/uqfoundation/dill/blob/master/dill/dill.py#L245

It's this line of code here. variable pik is used instead of pickler